# ValueError at /articles/article/19 The 'article_image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField



class Article(models.Model):
    author=models.ForeignKey("auth.User",on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Yazar")
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="Başlık") 
    content=RichTextField(verbose_name="İçerik")
    created_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name="Oluşturulma Tarihi")  
    article_image=models.FileField(blank=True,null=True,verbose_name="Fotoğraf Ekleyin")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

detail.html

```
<img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{{articles.article.article_image.url}}" alt="">
```

when i want add image to my articles i get error  and in my vs code it ot creare media folder  although i can see my articles but without photo and i can see text like html code not notmal (sorry for bad english)
'The 'article_image' attribute has no file associated with it.
'

i put all paths to settings.py but i couldnt solve it

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse,redirect,get_object_or_404
from . import forms
from .models import Article
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.

def index(request):  # Sayfada gorunmesi istedigimiz fonksiyonlari bu klasore yaziyoruz
    return render(request,"index.html") # bunlada sayfaya index dosyasini ekliyoruz

    #return HttpResponse("Anasayfa")  #Bu sekildede eklenebilir

def about(request):
    return render(request,"about.html")

def dashboard(request):
    articles=Article.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    context={
        "articles":articles
    }


    return render(request,"dashboard.html",context)

def addarticle(request):
    form =forms.ArticleForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        article=form.save(commit=False) # Formu kayd edecek ama bir degiskene atayacak commit=False o demekdirki auto kaydetme ozum manuel kayd edecem

        article.author=request.user
        article.save()

        messages.success(request,"Makale Başarıyla Oluşturuldu!")
        return render(request,"dashboard.html")



    context={
        "form":form
    }

    return render(request,"addarticle.html",context)


def showarticle(request,id):
    # article=Article.objects.filter(id=id).first() #listedeki gordugu ilk elemani alir
    article=get_object_or_404(Article,id=id) # 404 modulunu ekliyoruz ve yukaridakiyle ayni islem goruyor ama eger olmaya bir degere giderse 404 error veriyor
    context={
        "article":article
    }
    return render(request,"detail.html",context)
```

Comment: Likely `article_image` is `null` for this `Article`?

Comment: i solved this error  i wrote detail.html like that  <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{{articles.article.article_image.url}}" alt="">            but when i go into article i cant  see image it seems like empty    and when i write example hello is seems <p>Hello</p> how can i solve  and maybe you ll not understand cuz my englis is really awful hahahah

Comment: done...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your object does not finds an image it returns error, so you can add this it will check if model object has image or not. If it does not it will simple not execute `<img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{{ article.article_image.url }}" alt="">` ever.

```
{% if article.article_image %}
    <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{{ article.article_image.url }}" alt="">
{% endif %}
```